# Integration of django authentication system with Facebook API

Tags: django, facebook

I am integrating Django authentication and login system with Facebook Login API. The problem is that once Facebook username will be the same as existing in my project's database so the only solution to the problem is to catch Facebook username and add numbers or something to the string to make it unique ? Is it correct ? How is it normally handled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options, I'm sure I won't think of them all.

- If you have an unique constraint on the field for 'username', you can add numbers to remain unique.
- Remove the unique constraint on the 'username' field. Add a boolean to the user table, to identify users logging in with facebook. You are probably able to determine when a user logins with a facebook account. After logging in you can crossmatch the information with the user you have in the database. Facebook probably has some kind of 'unique' data about a specific user which you can place in your database to differentiate between unique users with the same name.